# Node JS app not processing php mailer code

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, phpmailer

I have a simple website built on Node JS framework with a php mailer to handle my contact form. I cannot seem to get it to work and I am wondering if there is an inherent problem with Node JS itself not being able to process the php code. It has one html page, index.html, which contains a the contact form code:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading" style="text-align: center;">Message</h2>
                <h3 class="text-muted">Want to book an appointment? Send me a message and I'll contact you. Make sure you include your name, phone number, email, and when you'd like to book. It's that easy!</h3>
                <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" action="contact_me.php" method="post" novalidate>
                    <div style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid #0085a1;" class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid #0085a1;" class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label></label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" name="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid #0085a1;" class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label></label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" name="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid #0085a1;" class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label></label>
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" name="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

At the same folder level, there is a contact_me.php file:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
  empty($_POST['email'])        ||
  empty($_POST['phone'])        ||
  empty($_POST['message'])  ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
  echo "No arguments Provided!";
  return false;
  }

$to = 'jcbridwe@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: 
$email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers = "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Whenever I hit "submit" at the bottom of my form, I get the following error: "Cannot POST /contact_me.php". After some experimentation, I added an echo statement into the php code (I have a very limited understanding of php) and determined that while the node server is running, the php does not seem to process. If this is the case, what can I do to resolve this issue? Is there something in a route.js or index.js (under Node's Express Server folder) that I need to add in order for the php mailer to work?

Comment: how are you running your node ? and where is ur php file.? Who is handling requests for the php ?

Comment: and why cant u send the email from node? why do u need php to do it?

Comment: 1. comment out the strings with `replacing yourname@yourdomain.com ...` and `message to.` 2. the header `Reply-To: $email_address` must be without line breaks.

Comment: @Panther - I am not sure what you mean when you ask "How are you running node?" I have the app on a Cloud9 IDE, I use `$node server` command to run it, and push changes to git and heroku for the live version. This is a simple website, and using NodeJS is probably overkill, but I thought I might need to add functionality in the future. Both the index.html and contact_me.php files sit under the client folder on the same level. Handling php? I am not using AJAX, if thats what you mean. I was using php because I thought it would be easy and all I would need was a simple `action` command.

Comment: @Deadooshka - Sorry, a syntax error. I have edited the post and the correct code is there.

Comment: is there a php-interpreter? Clarify the php configuration.

Comment: Node.js doesn't know anything about php. So you'll need to have a server that knows about it (Apache, ngnix...), or run the command-line php interpreter from your Node.js script (probably the most awful idea), or write the form handling and mailing code in Javascript.

Comment: OK, that was actually the answer I was looking for. So, NodeJS doesn't know what to do with php unless it has an interpreter. And it wouldn't make sense to have Apache server when Node already has Express. In essense, what you are saying is that it doesn't make a lot of sense to use a php mailer in NodeJS and that an alternative solution  would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I learning NodeJS same. Why you dont want to use [Nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) with ExpressJS? Its easy to use and setup.

Comment: OK, I am trying to figure out Nodemailer. At https://nodemailer.com/usage/. I have installed the nodemailer via `$npm install nodemailer` into the `node_modules` directory. It then tells you to "create a transport object" using SMTP or something similar. A code example is given but it doesn't tell you where the code goes (in what file, in what folder). It also doesn't explain how its wired up to the form in my index.html. Can you tell me where the transport object code goes? I'm looking at some tutorials, but they all leave out these important details.

Comment: Look [into my repo](https://github.com/PinkyRabbit/usenodemailer) i maked working example

Comment: That's great, thanks! So essentially, the transport object and configuration go in the index.js file under the routes folder in Express. That is exactly the answer I've been looking for. I am working on getting it plugged in now.

Comment: I still have a question. What folder is the index.js file in your example. Is it to go under node_modules/express or node_modules/nodemailer. I do not have any file called "routes" under my nodemailer directory. I do have a folder called "routers" under my express directory, but this does not seem like the correct place to add that code. Or, am I to add a folder called 'nodemailer' under the client directory that contains the routes/index.js file as well as all the accompanying folders and files?

Comment: I use Express application generator for starting expressjs projects. [Link to turtorial](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). After calling express in your CLI you will have all standart files and folders from start. All dependencies that i used into example you can find into _package.json_ file. Just type `npm install --save` for installing dependencies